# Networkdays Function

Tags: excel

Having a problem with the `=NETWORKDAYS()` function.

[image]

I would like to include two Holiday ranges - Holidays 1 and Holidays 2. The function seems to only allow for 1 range. Any ideas on how to get this to also include cell A2?

My current formula is `=NETWORKDAYS(C2,D2,A2:A11)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming *Holidays1* and *Holidays2* are both **vertical** ranges:

`=NETWORKDAYS(C2,D2,CHOOSE({1,2},Holidays1,Holidays2))`

If you're not using an English-language version of Excel then the separator for horizontal arrays, i.e. the comma in the part

`{1,2}`

may need amending.

A non-locale-dependent version, for those who have access to the `SEQUENCE` function:

`=NETWORKDAYS(C2,D2,CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,2),Holidays1,Holidays2))`